Individually coloured markers in QField
Is there a way to individually change the colour of markers in QField (from QGIS) so that multiple users can 'mark them off'?

You should be able to do that with a simple classification based on a specific field  or a ruled based symbology (such as "field_date" is not null or "field_status" is 'seen')
https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html
